# Images scrolling with page

Tags: image, inheritance, scroll, position, fixed

I need help with a CSS property I can't understand.

I have two images supposed to scroll down the window but only one does it.

Left one works fine, but the right one (Facebook logo) does not move.

URL is : http://www.antoinewistaff.com

I have the part of CSS here :

```
#clients    {float:left; position:fixed; top:0; padding:0px 0px 0px 50px;}
#facebook   {float:right; position:inherit; top:0; padding:0px 50px 0px 0px;}
```

YES I had to put `position:inherit;` for the `#facebook` line because otherwise it goes right over the other one (left side instead of right side) maybe I missed something there?

I TRIED BOTH with `position:fixed;` and it just put both on left side (scrolling, but not on their side)

I hope it's clear, and someone can help me :)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Zach, Worked perfect! Thank you!

I tried to vote up your post but apparently I'm not allowed until I reach 15 reputations....

But thank and it works, good job !

Comment: You can click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct (: This gives both the answer-er and the OP (Original Poster - you) reputation for doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `right` to place it on the right side. And floats will not affect any element with `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`

```
#facebook {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

Valid properties that elements with absolute or fixed positioning can use to position themselves are the following:

- `top`
- `left`
- `botttom`
- `right`
- margins (negative and positive for each direction)

Also note that one cannot apply both a `top` & `bottom` or `left` & `right`, the one that is placed after the other will be used